# How many functions (Counting problem)

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A$ be a set of size $25$ and let $B$ be a set of size $17$. How many functions $f\colon A\to B$ are there?

1. $17!$
2. $\frac{25!}{17!}$
3. $17^{25}$
4. $25^{17}$

I think the answer is 3. Is it?

Comment: yes, but convince yourself. Why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes: (cardinality of codomain) to the power of (cardinality of domain) is right.

Comment: This doesn't explain why nor does it give any hints or intuitions.

Answer (score 3):

A set is a group of **unique** elements (in opposed to a multi-set).

A function $f : A \rightarrow B$ maps **every** element in the domain $A$ to a **single** element in the range $B$.

You have $25$ elements in the domain $A$ and $17$ elements in the range $B$.

Each element in the domain $A$ must be mapped to an element in the range $B$:

- The 1st element in the domain $A$ has $17$ mapping options in the range $B$
- The 2nd element in the domain $A$ has $17$ mapping options in the range $B$
- The 3rd element in the domain $A$ has $17$ mapping options in the range $B$
- ...
- The 25th element in the domain $A$ has $17$ mapping options in the range $B$

So the total number of **different** mappings (i.e., functions) from $A$ to $B$ is: $$17 \times 17 \times 17 \times \dots \times 17 = 17^{25}$$